# Need MDM to in iOS APP

Tags: ios, mdm

I have one iOS app in Appstore. Now I want to implement the Mobile Device Management in it. As per the online documentations, I came to know that it needs Enterprise Developer Program for this and some sites are saying that It works only for the in-House apps. But I want the app to place in Appstore after implementing MDM. Please let me know the way how can I achieve this.

Comment: The doesn't sound like a coding issue, what are you trying to achieve with MDM?

Comment: This is a parental guidance app. And app needs to remotely manage the child's device like blocking the Games, Videos...(Sample app https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/parentkit-parental-controls/id600618138?mt=8)

Comment: From the looks of that app they are using their own cloud-based MDM environment, so the MDM isn't in their app.  Their app simply updates the profile on the MDM server that is pushed to the managed device.

Comment: Hi Paulw, seems you are correct. But, to maintain own MDM server Apple says to have Enterprise account and MDM services will be provided which can be used only for In-House Apps can be developed which can't be placed in Appstore.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not related to coding - it deals with distribution of apps

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is pretty vague.
You cannot implement MDM related features in App. 
By default IOS 4 or later comes with MDM framework. You have to distribute configuration profile with MDM payload to device, inorder to configure it against an MDM server.Afterwards MDM server can send remote management commands, restrictions and policies.

***As per the online documentations, I came to know that it needs Enterprise Developer Program for this and some sites are saying that It works only for the in-House apps.***

- The uses of Enterprise account are, Apple has mandated Enterprise
  Developer Program account to get to know about [MDM protocol](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fdevcenter%2Fdownload.action%3Fpath%3D%2FDocuments%2Fmobile_device_management_protocol%2Fmobiledevicemanagementprotocol.pdf&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFJsGPLJqIlwrohE_jrBEeW0juxDw).
- Using Enterprise account only you can download MDM CSR certificate
  which will be later used for signing CSR produced by user to get APNS
  certificate. MDM has nothing to do with Inhouse applications.

**1.)** Please have a look at [Over the air profile delivery](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/iPhoneOTAConfiguration/Introduction/Introduction.html) document by apple. It will give you plenty of information to transfer the Configuration profile Over the air.

**2.)** Explore [MDM Protocol](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fdevcenter%2Fdownload.action%3Fpath%3D%2FDocuments%2Fmobile_device_management_protocol%2Fmobiledevicemanagementprotocol.pdf&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFJsGPLJqIlwrohE_jrBEeW0juxDw) document provided by Apple and then look at [wonderful document on MDM](http://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf) by Intrepidus Group, Inc.

**3.)** Read [Configuration profile key reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html) document, to understand the properties used in configuration profile and Payload specific properties(Ex: Wifi Payload related properties)

**4.)** Then start constructing your own MDM server to handle MDM requests.!

***But I want the app to place in Appstore after implementing MDM. Please let me know the way how can I achieve this.***

May be in your app, you can give option to download configuration profile with MDM settings after authorization, if you doesn't want to send enrolment request for user through email or by any other means..